# PA, provably total function, Gödel's T

Tags: computability-theory, proof-theory

If I am not mistaken, the provably total functions of $PA$ are exactly those definable in terms of the functionals of higher type $T$, as introduced by Gödel in his 1958 *Dialectica* paper.

In particular, for theories $\Sigma_n-IA$, the fragments of $PA$ where induction is restricted to $\Sigma_n$ formulae, and for the classes of functions definable in terms of $T_n$, the fragments of $T$ limited to recursors $R_\sigma$, for $\sigma$ of rank at most $n$ (where $\operatorname{rank}(0)=0$, $\operatorname{rank}(\sigma(\tau))= \operatorname{max}(\operatorname{rank}(\sigma)+1,\operatorname{rank}(\tau))$, the provable total function of $\Sigma_n-IA$ are characterized as those definable in terms of the functionals of higher type $T_n$.

If it is so, I am looking for a detailed, direct proof of it (both directions). In particular, I do kind of remember that to prove that any function definable in term of $T_n$ is provably total in $\Sigma_n-IA$, the way to go is to formalize Tait's computability predicate.  I am interested to double check that that is the case, and –if it is– it would be great to look at a reference where all the details has been spelled out.

('direct' means without any detour to ordinal recursion, or Grzegorczyk functions.)

Comment: Using notation of simply-typed $\lambda$-calculus, does $\sigma(\tau)$ mean $\sigma \to \tau$ or $\tau \to \sigma$? The definition of rank looks strange. The ranks of $(\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{N}$ and  $\mathbb{N} \to (\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N})$ should not be the same.

Comment: I would say $\sigma \to \tau$. Yes, those two ranks should be different. Maybe rank($\sigma(\tau)$)= max(rank($\sigma$)+1,rank($\tau$))?

Comment: Yes, that would be the usual definition of rank.

Comment: Good, thanks. I edit the question.

Comment: In Shoenfield's mathematical logic, pp.224--227, you will find a reasonably detailed and direct proof of the general case (provably recursive function of $PA$ iff designated by some constant of $T$). The converse implication is proved by formalizing the reducibility predicate. It may be possible, by a careful analysis of the proof, to extract a direct proof of the result you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did not check Shoenfield's, my fault.  If I am not misreading him, for the PA to T direction he goes thru the Kreisel's no-counterexample interpretation; for the T to PA direction, he claims that the relevant propositions about Tait's reducibility predicate can be proved within PA (of course, for each single type $\sigma$). I understand that it is moderately easy to fill in all the details but I still hope that somebody has already done all the work (for fragments too).